# parse an xml for a particular element value

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

i have a xml like

```
{
<TrainTime>
<Train number="1">
<trainData>
<entry id="111"/>
<stations>
<station name="s1" id="s_s1" dep="11:10:00" arr=""/>
<station name="s2" id="s_s2" dep="" arr=""/>
<station name="s3" id="s_s3" dep="" arr=""/>
.
.
.
</stations>
</trainData>
</train>
<Train number="5">
<trainData>
<entry id="222"/>
<stations>
<station name="t1" id="s_t1" dep="" arr=""/>
<station name="t2" id="s_t2" dep="" arr=""/>
<station name="t3" id="s_t3" dep="" arr=""/>
.
.
.
 </stations>
</trainData>
</train>
</TrainTime>
}
```

Similarly, I have many train Numbers and their details. I want to parse the xml for a particular train number and get all the details related to it.
Like if I want to get the details for train number 2.

I am using xpath as:

```
{xPath = "//Train[@number='1'/trainData/stations";}
```

Its not working and whats the correct way?
Can this also be done through Linq Xml? How?

Comment: Side notes - you have `station` elements not closed here. Also `stations` is not closed. Also start tag `Train` does not match end tag `train`. Too many errors. Please, post valid xml

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: sorry.. i have edited it now.. I can't post the actual xml here as it is more detailed than this so just posted a sample structure only to explain my problem in short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for XPath and Linq to Xml:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var data = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//Train[@number='1']/trainData");
                                                       ^
```

You are missing closing bracket in your XPath query. That query will give you `trainData` XElement if there is any train matching your number in xml. Further parsing is simple:

```
if (data != null)
{
    int entryId = (int)data.Element("entry").Attribute("id");
    var stations = data.Element("stations")
                       .Elements("station")
                       .Select(s => new {
                            Name = (string)s.Attribute("name"),
                            Id = (string)s.Attribute("id"),
                            Arrival = (string)s.Attribute("arr"),
                            Departure = (string)s.Attribute("dep")
                       }).ToList();
}
```

You can also use pure Linq query without XPath. Following query will return first matching anonymous train object (if any) with its number, entry id and stations:

```
int number = 1; // number of train to find
var train = (from t in xdoc.Root.Elements("Train")
             let d = t.Element("trainData")
             where (int)t.Attribute("number") == number
             select new {
                Number = number,
                EntryId = (int)d.Element("entry").Attribute("id"),
                Stations = (from s in d.Element("stations").Elements("station")
                            select new {
                                 Name = (string)s.Attribute("name"),
                                 Id = (string)s.Attribute("id"),
                                 Arrival = (string)s.Attribute("arr"),
                                 Departure = (string)s.Attribute("dep")
                            }).ToList()
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

---

NOTE - thus your sample xml is not valid (see comment under question) I assumed you have following structure of xml:

```
<TrainTime>
  <Train number="1">
    <trainData>
      <entry id="111"/>
      <stations>
        <station name="s1" id="s_s1" dep="11:10:00" arr=""/>
        <station name="s2" id="s_s2" dep="" arr=""/>
        <station name="s3" id="s_s3" dep="" arr=""/>
      </stations>
    </trainData>
  </Train>
  <Train number="5">
    <trainData>
      <entry id="222"/>
      <stations>
        <station name="t1" id="s_t1" dep="" arr=""/>
        <station name="t2" id="s_t2" dep="" arr=""/>
        <station name="t3" id="s_t3" dep="" arr=""/>
      </stations>
    </trainData>
  </Train>
</TrainTime>
```

If some names do not match, update query appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have placed the missing bracket but I am getting error @ var train = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//Train[@number='1']");
has some invalid arguments..

Comment: @Vipasha make sure you have referenced `System.Xml.Linq` and `System.Xml.XPath` namespaces

Comment: @Vipasha I just verified query - it works fine. Make sure your code does not differs from mine. Note - I updated query due to element name changes in your sample xml

Comment: thanks all the solutions suggested by you are working..I prefer the one without XPath.